# SQL Server sum two columns from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables:

- Table `Customer`: id_customer, customer
- Table `Product`: id_product, product
- `Table1`: id_t1_main, year, month
- `Table2`: id_t1_main, id_customer, id_product, amount
- `Table3`: id_t3_main, year, month
- `Table4`: id_t3_main, id_customer, id_product, price

What I want is:

```
customer, product, sum(amount), sum(price)
```

I mean, sum of amount, sum of price, group by customer & product, for a specific year & month.

Comment: So just join the tables. Do the group by. Done! (Perhaps left joins.)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Seems to be a simple join solution.

Comment: Please update the question to (1) show how the tables relate to each other, (2) explain what the `id_t1_main` column is, and (3) explain what the `id_t3_main` column is. With that additional information it's more likely your question can be answered, whereas right now any answer would involve a lot of guessing.

Comment: Join `TableCustomer, Table2` and `Table4` over `id_customer` let you combine customer with amount and price. Join the result with `Table1` and `Table2` let you combine customer, amount and price with year and month. Now you can sum of price and amount, group by customer in a standard way with `SUM()`and `GROUP BY`. The same is also for products using  `TableProduct`.